# What are the differences, if any, between Little Big Planet GOTY Edition, and the one in PS3's Welcome Back offer?

Tags: little-big-planet, psn

I recently purchased LBP GotY edition, just before realizing the game would be available in the Welcome Back offer after the outage in PSN.

Before returning the game (which has yet to be delivered) and downloading the one in the Welcome Back, I'd like to know if there's any difference between the two, in which case I'd just choose another game from the offer and keep the GotY edition (or not, if the difference is not substantial enough)

Comment: This is most likely going to be closed due to being too localized (in time)

Comment: @Wipqozn: Since the welcome-back version will remain available (for sale) on the PSN after the welcome-back program is over, I don't think this is too localized.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I was looking at from the point of view that it had more to do with which one to purchase, which would obviously be irrelevant a month from now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GOTY edition comes with a selection of DLC (mostly costumes, although the excellent MGS level pack is also included) which the welcome back (standard) edition doesn't.

For a complete listing of extra content, see [this post](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2009/08/17/announcing-littlebigplanet-%E2%80%93-game-of-the-year-edition/)

You could always get the welcome back version and buy the DLC separately.